# Why is the model binder mixing up ID fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a model that is used to add a new address, in the view the `ShopId` is in a `HiddenFor` and the `ID` is `0`, also the FK `Shop` is `null` so there is no `ID` set in it.

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string ShopId { get; set; }
public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }
public string District { get; set; }
public string Region { get; set; }
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
public int CountryId { get; set; }
public System.DateTime CreationTimestamp { get; set; }
public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
public Nullable<double> Latitude { get; set; }
public Nullable<double> Longitude { get; set; }

public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
public virtual Shop Shop{ get; set; }
```

When I post the form the `ModelState.IsValid` is showing as `false` saying that the value that was in the `ShopId` is invalid in the `ID` field:

> The value 'd04bf59f-be29-4896-ae70-54432b02aa46' is not valid for ID.

Why is the model binding placing the `ShopId` into the `ID` field?

Here's the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ShopAddress</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ShopId)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine1, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressLine1, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine1)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine2, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressLine2, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddressLine3, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AddressLine3, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine3)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.District, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.District, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.District)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Region, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Region, new { @class = "form-control" })    
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Region)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PostalCode, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostalCode)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Country, "Country", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsPrimary, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPrimary, "true") Yes
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsPrimary, "false") No
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i resolved this finally, the reason the ShopId was being placed in the ID field was because the ID was being taken from the url, D'oh!!!!

The page url was **/shops/add-address/d04bf59f-be29-4896-ae70-54432b02aa46** and then on the HTTPPOST the modelbinder was quite rightly taking the id (guid) and moving it by convention to the models ID property.

Instead, i did what i should have done in the first place and created a viewModel and then used autoMapper to map object to object.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: or just pass shopId to url insteal of id

Answer (score 0):

most probably binder tries to do his best to find value for id, and since it's not presented in the view, it will take a field which has 'id" in it's name. Try to add a hidden field for id or create a model for this view instead of passing a domain object

Comment: Hi Artiom, I have tried this already, no luck because the Id is always 0 because it is a new address being added. still it insists on mapping the ShopId to the Id property.